# Django functional test: selenium.quit() doesn't reset database?

Tags: django, selenium, python-unittest

```
class FunctionalTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp")
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        print("tearDown")
        self.browser.quit()


class MyTest(FunctionalTest):

    def test1(self):
        cart = Cart.objects.create()
        print(cart.id)

    def test2(self):
        cart = Cart.objects.create()
        print(cart.id)

    def test3(self):
        cart = Cart.objects.create()
        print(cart.id)
```

When I run the test,

```
setUp
1
tearDown
.setUp
2
tearDown
.setUp
3
tearDown
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 7.024s
```

I don't understand why each test function's result affect other test function(`cart`'s `id`)

What I expected :

```
setUp
1
tearDown
.setUp
1
tearDown
.setUp
1
tearDown
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 7.024s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what's happening here. Your tests are **not** getting in each other's ways.

LiveServerTestcase is a subclass of [TransactionTestcase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase) and

> A TransactionTestCase resets the database after the test runs by
>   truncating all tables. A TransactionTestCase may call commit and
>   rollback and observe the effects of these calls on the database.

Truncating tables does not reset the auto icnrement counter. By default all django models have an auto incrementing primary key.

When you do the following you are merely printing out the primary key of the most recently created model and that's increasing all the time.

```
 print(cart.id)
```

Instead, what you should do is

```
 self.assertEqual(1,Cart.objects.count())
```

Comment: Ah... I didn't know about that.. What a precious information. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have been of help